# Using server-side events (SSE) to push updates to web client using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

I'm trying to use server-side events (SSE) in Javascript and Node.JS to push updates to a web client.
To keep things simple, I have a function which will generate the time every second:

```
setTimeout(function time() {
  sendEvent('time', + new Date);
  setTimeout(time, uptimeTimeout);
}, 1000);
```

The sendEvent function puts together the event in the expected format and sends it to the client.

```
var clientRes;
var lastMessageId = 0;
function sendEvent(event, message) {
  message = JSON.stringify(message);
  ++lastMessageId;
  sendSSE(clientRes, lastMessageId, event, message);
}
```

The clientRes value comes from the server function to handle the route from the base URL.

```
    app.use('/', function (req, res) {
        clientRes = res;
        ...
    }
```

What I want to achieve at the client UI is a simple page which shows:

```
>   <h1>The current time is {event.data}</h1>
```

where I derive the current time from the latest message data received from the server.

I have created an index.html file to have the client listen for these server-sent messages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
  console.log("Event source is supported");
  var source = new EventSource("localhost:3000");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "=>" + event.data + "<br>";
  };
} else {
  console.log("Event source not supported");
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
evtSource.addEventListener("time", function(event) {
  const newElement = document.createElement("li");
  const time = JSON.parse(event.data).time;
  console.log("Time listener found time " + time);
  newElement.innerHTML = "ping at " + time;
  eventList.appendChild(newElement);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I respond to a GET request with this index.html, I don't see any of the time messages.
That is, this server code does not work:

```
app.use("/", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    clientRes = response;
});
```

However if I don't respond with the index.html file and allow the server to push timestamps to the client, they to show up in the browser:

```
event: time
id: 104
data: 1587943717153

event: time
id: 105
data: 1587943727161
...
```

Here's is where I'm stuck.
It appears I have successfully gotten the server to push new timestamps every second.
And the browser is seeing them and displaying the text. 
But the arrival of the message from the server is not triggering the listener and the message is not being rendered based on the index.html.

Most of the examples I've seen for use of SSE involves a PHP data source. I need for the server to both generate the data and to provide the HTML to display it.
I've been successful in one or the other, but not both at the same time.

Comment: The first thing I'll point out is that you can't save `clientRes` at a scope outside the Express route handler because that means each route will overwrite the previous one.  All module scoped variables are shared by all the routes.  Instead, you need to call your code from inside the route and pass it the `res` scoped there.  This is not the problem you're asking about, but quickly will become a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was missing.
I did not specify the endpoints correctly.
For the root endpoint, the server code needs to deliver the index.html file.

```
app.use("/", function(request, response) {
    console.log("In root handler");
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

Index.html contains the script that creates the event source:

```
    var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:3000/time");
```

But the URL that gets passed in as the input to the EventSource constructor must be a different endpoint (not root). It needs to be the endpoint that generates the timestamps.
So in the server, the handler for the /time endpoint is the one which pushes the data.

```
app.use('/time', function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'content-type': 'text/event-stream',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'connection': 'keep-alive'
      });

      // Save the response 
      clientRes = res;
});
```